# What algorithm to manage several timers that must not interfere with each other in obj-c (Slideshow)?

Tags: objective-c, architecture, timer, core-animation, slideshow

I' making an app that slideshows several views, photos and stuff like that. If the user doesn't do anything, then it change the view each few seconds. If the user swipe, then the slideshow must stop, and let him navigate manually.

In the background, the app check for new content. If new content is available, it must show the most up-to-date view to the user (if is not doing anything).

The app show the view full-screen. If the user tap the view, the nav bar is displayed so they can change settings. If they do nothing for a while, then the slideshow start again and the nav bar is hide.

So far, 3 timers. Now, I wonder if there exists an elegant way to make them not interfere with each other.

Is incorrect to move the slideshow if the user is exploring the settings (before him navigate away), also is not ok to interrupt him when explore each view manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just create 3 timers and manage according your algorytm.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *slideshowTimer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *networkUpdatesTimer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *idleTimer;
```

In correct moments schedule and unshedule each timer this way,

Schedule:

```
self.slideshowTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(slideshowTimerFired:) repeats:NO];
```

Implement selector which you pass into timer initialization method.

unschedule:

```
[self.slideshowTimer invalidate];
```

As you can see each particular timer will have a partucular selector.
And be careful cause NSTimer retains it's own target until it will be invalidated (unscheduled).

Comment: That is the manual way. I wonder if exist a algorithm that could be used to control this different to use control flags...

Comment: While you looking for this algorithm you can implement this manually better and effective I think) so you can you cam schedule a single times with one second and call it update: like in gamedev paradigm and use control flags to implement it